# how to convert an ascii number 057836 to a packed bcd number using 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086, bcd

I am having problems converting ascii numbers to BCD numbers.
I know that converting small numbers is done by subtracting 30h from each number, but with this big number I don't know how to deal with it, I thought of dividing the number Into bytes, but am not sure if this idea is right or not ..

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Show an example of how you convert small numbers, then it will be easy to demonstrate how it's done with larger values.

Comment: Are you allowed/required to use BCD-specific instructions (AAA, AAD, etc)?

Comment: Dependings a on what exactly you need, but the `FBSTP` instruction might be your friend: It converts a floating point value to a BCD number.

Comment: yes I am allowed to use these kind of instructions like(aaa ,aad,aam,aas)

Comment: @Shift_Left you can convert ascii numbers to unpacked bcd by subtracting 30 from each number

Comment: @PMF    yes I am allowed to use these kind of instructions like(aaa ,aad,aam,aas)

Answer (score 2):

The packed BCD number 057836 doesn't fit in a single 16-bit register. emu8086 does not allow the use of 32-bit registers, as it has been possible in 16-bit mode since the 80386 processor. So, use two registers to get the packed BCD. I used `AX` and `DX`. To get place for a new BCD number in the rightmost 4 bits of `AX`, you have to shift left 4 bits from `AX` to `DX`:

```
.MODEL small

.DATA
    bcd db "057836", 0

.CODE

main PROC
    mov ax, @data           ; Initialize DS
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, OFFSET bcd      ; Initialize registers for the loop
    mov ax, 0
    mov dx, 0

    loo:                    ; Loop through the ASCII string
    mov bl, [si]            ; Get a character
    cmp bl, 0               ; End of String reached?
    je endloo               ; Yes -> exit the loop

    ; Make space for a bcd number shifting left 4 bits from AX to DX
    ; 4 single shifts because emu8086 doesn't support `SHLD`
    shl ax, 1
    rcl dx, 1
    shl ax, 1
    rcl dx, 1
    shl ax, 1
    rcl dx, 1
    shl ax, 1
    rcl dx, 1

    and bl, 0Fh             ; Delete the ASCII-part (same as sub bl, 30h)
    or al, bl               ; Transfer number from bl to al

    inc si                  ; Next character
    jmp loo                 ; Once more
    endloo:

    ; At this point the register pair DX:AX contains the packed BCD number

    mov ax, 4C00h           ; Exit (0)
    int 21h                 ; Call MSDOS
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help,,,,i appreciate it so much ,,,,but I just have one question how can I make sure that my final result is correct ?

Comment: @taniamiah: Click in emu8086 on `emulate`. Highlight in the source code window the line with `endloo:`. Choose in the emulator window `debug - set breakpoint (...)`. Click in the emulator window on `run`. The emulator will stop at `mov ax, 4C00h` and you can examine the registers at the left side in the emulator window.

Comment: what I mean is how can I know that the result in the register is right plus I would like to tell u that I tried your code and it converts only the first number 0

Comment: @taniamiah: A packed BCD number in hexadecimal notation should look like a decimal number. So, `DX` should contain 0005h and `AX` 7836h. I tested my code and it works correct.